# Replacing contents inside curly braces (for e.g. {1}) with something else

Tags: java, string

I have a string as follows

```
Hey {1}, you are {2}.
```

Here `1` and `2` are key whose value will be added dynamically.

Now I need to replace `{1}` with the value that `1` represents and then I need to replace `{2}` with the value that `2` represents in the sentence above.

How do I do it?

I know what split function of a string does and I know very well that with that function I can do what I want but I am looking for something better.

**Note:** I don't know what these keys are in advance. I need to retrieve the keys as well. And then according to the keys I need to replace the values in the string.

Comment: Not a bad question.. Why the downvote?

Comment: @Smrita you want to replace `{1}` and `{2}` from your string and there are only two values in your string that you want to replace not more than 2 is that right..

Comment: Not really i will have many values:).

Comment: So it means your string also look like this `Hey {1} , you are {2} and you can {3} with {4}` and so on.....and you have to replace all the values in the braces

Comment: @amitbhardwaj yes thats my case:).

Comment: From the comments you're leaving @Smrita, I'm getting the impression that the keys could be anything. Like {key} for example. Is that correct?

Comment: @Smrita and your key in string is always integer or it could be anything

Comment: I have given a solution considering you use a hashmap (and without checking any exceptions). You need to provide more information..

Comment: @DanTemple and Amit  keys will integers and they will be inside curley braces {}.

Comment: @Smrita: From where are you getting values to be replaced for `1`, `2`, `3` etc?

Comment: @anubhava the keys will be stored in the database

Comment: ok but how are you keeping those keys and values in your Java code? Are you using a `Map`?

Comment: @anubhava yes I am using a Map to keep them.

Comment: In that case did you take a look at answer from @TheLostMind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava for this one.. :). You could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Hey {1}, you are {2}.";
    HashMap<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap();
    hm.put(1, "one");
    hm.put(2, "two");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\{\\d+\\})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
        String val1 = m.group().replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
        System.out.println(val1);
        s = (s.replace(m.group(), hm.get(Integer.parseInt(val1))));
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Hey one, you are two.
```

Comment: Thank you It works:). TheLostMind rocks:)

Comment: @Smrita - Good luck trying to modify it for more than 2 values :P

Comment: This idea is fine but matching and replacement should be done in a `while (m.find()) {...}` loop using a simple regex `\\{(\\d+)\\}`

Comment: @anubhava - yes.. I agree.. I simply complicated the problem.. and was in a hurry to post the solution :P

Comment: @Smrita - Use the updated answer. It is better than the earlier one :)

Comment: Nice, but maybe not very efficient

Answer (score 14):

You can use **MessageFormat** from java.text.MessageFormat. 
[Message Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) has some example on how it can be used in this type of scenario

Answer (score 4):

Try using [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
String x = String.format("Hi %s, you are %s\n", str1, str2);
```

If you have already a string `"Hey {1}, you are {2}."` you can use regular expressions to replace `{1}` and `{2}` with `%s`.

```
String template = "Hey {1}, you are {2}.";
String x = String.format(template.replaceAll("\\{\\d\\}", "%s"), "Name", "Surname");
```

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot use it!

Comment: @Smrita can't you use format?

Answer (score 4):

Try this i think this will work from what i understand from your question

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       String str = "Hey {1} your {2} is {3}  clear to {4}  ";
       Map<Integer,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();
       map.put(1, "Smrita");
       map.put(2, "question");
       map.put(3, "not");
       map.put(4, "anyone");
       while(str.contains("{")){
           Integer i = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(str.indexOf("{")+1, str.indexOf("{")+2));
           str = str.replace("{"+i+"}", map.get(i));

       }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

**the output is**

`Hey Smrita your question is not  clear to anyone`

Comment: aah.. Some of us always tend to ignore the beauty of simplicity. :). +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String str = "Hey {1}, you are {2}.";
str = str.replaceFirst("\\{.*?\\}", "Matt");
```

Output:

```
Hey Matt, you are {2}.
```

The above code will replace the first instance of `{1}`. If you call this sequence in a loop replacing with the key values from your code, it'll replace all strings within `{...}` in the order mentioned in the given string.