# How to replace all matched text with dynamic group?

Tags: java, regex

If I got a `String`=**"#1 and #2"**, a `Map`={"1":"a", "2":"b"}, What I indend to do is to replace `#x` with the value evaluated from `Map(x)`, whose result should be **"a and b"**.

My code is as follows:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("1", "a");
    map.put("2", "b");
    String s = "#1 and #2";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#(.*?)(\\s|$)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find())        {
        s = m.replaceFirst(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

But the output is infinite like:

```
1and #2
2and #2
2and #2
2and #2
...
...
```

Could anyone give me an explanation on this phenomennon, as well as give me a proper solution to my problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256469/replacing-contents-inside-curly-braces-for-e-g-1-with-something-else?noredirect=1#comment37470934_24256469 might help

Comment: Thanks bro, this helps. But could you explain why my code would end up with an infinite loop? @TheLostMind

Comment: The regex is partially wrong.. and you are replacing s by calling replaceFirst on the matcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex pattern to `#(\d+)` to make it simple.

Sample code 1:  (*using String#replaceAll()*)

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("1", "a");
map.put("2", "b");
String s = "#1 and #2";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    String match = m.group(1);
    s = s.replaceAll("#"+match, map.get(match));
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Sample code 2: (*using Matcher#appendReplacement()*)

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("1", "a");
map.put("2", "b");
String s = "#1 and #2";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(buffer, map.get(m.group(1)));
}
System.out.println(buffer);
```

Please have a look at [`Matcher`'s documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), where a lot more stuff is covered in detail.

The post [Java Regex Replace with Capturing Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277157/java-regex-replace-with-capturing-group) might help you to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("1", "a");
    map.put("2", "b");
    String s = "#1 and #2";
    String result = null ;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#(\\d+).*#(\\d)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if(m.find()){
       result = s.replaceFirst("#\\d+", map.get(m.group(1)));
       result = result.replaceFirst("#\\d+", map.get(m.group(2)));
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```